# How to create an oblique multi line paragraph (HTML CSS)?

Tags: html, css

I need to create a multi line oblique paragraph, as in each line is progressively indented so that the left edge of the paragraph will create an oblique line (instead of a perfectly vertical one).

A very clumsy attempt would be like this (but I am wondering if there is a more elegant solution):

```
<p style="font-style: oblique;">
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;This is an oblique paragraph.<br />
&nbsp;&nbsp;This paragraph continues.<br />
&nbsp;This paragraph continues.<br />
This paragraph continues...</p>
```

Which results in this:

*This is a paragraph, oblique.
  This paragraph continues.
 This paragraph continues.
This paragraph continues...*

Thanks! ...or even better: *Thanks!* :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using [`skew()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/skew)

```css
p {
  transform: skewX(-20deg);
  padding: 40px;
}
```

```html
<p>
  Some text <br>
  Some text <br>
  Some text <br>
  Some text <br>
</p>
```

Nothing much to explain here, am just using `skew` to tilt the `p` text by `-20deg`, you can do `20deg` if you want to skew the text in the opposite direction.

Comment: That's great! Thanks. I just looked it up on W3School's 2D Transforms. This is supported on Explorer 10+ only, correct?

Comment: This is a good solution in my mind as well. Also, IE 9 and older can die a painful death as far as I'm concerned